# Error installing Codename One plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, codenameone, macos-sierra

I started developing in Codename One a few days ago, using IntelliJ, but since it was causing some problems, I decided to try it with Eclipse.

I got a fresh install of Eclipse Proton for Java developers on my Mac Pro running OS Sierra 10.12.6 and I can't install the Codename One plugin.

I can find it in the marketplace, but when I try to install it starts the process but soon stops and pops this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpqio.png). After I press ok, I can select features to install as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7zG.png). After I press Confirm it does nothing, and presents [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pvvg.png). I have already installed other plugins successfully, this is the only one giving me troubles.

I tried accessing that link but it leads to a standard 404 error page on codenameone's website.

I can't seem to find a way around this, as even trying to install the plugin through Eclipse marketplace website leads to this error.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: That's odd, I just installed the plugin from the marketplace on a fresh eclipse install using a Mac. That URL indeed doesn't exist but eclipse shouldn't search for it either. Which JDK is used in your eclipse installation within the `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: On my Eclipse IDE Installation Details it specifies:
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib
@ShaiAlmog

Comment: Can you try pointing it at JDK 8 and see if that works? I don't have newer JDK's on my system as they break a whole slew of tools I depend on. One of my colleagues tested eclipse with JDK 11 but he might have skipped the installation process as it's not something that "should" break. If JDK 8 fixes this issue we might need to evaluate that.

Comment: Did just that and it worked. Installed perfectly on the first try and already successfully ran the barebones Hello World.

I did't really pay attention to the jdk, it was required 8 or higher and since I had 11 I didn't give it a second thought. Thanks so much for your help, and for the attention you give your users.